# glDrawArrays allocates memory on every frame

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, glsl

I recently found that glDrawArrays allocating and releasing huge amounts of memory on every frame. 
I suspect that it's related to "Shaders compiled outside of initialization" issue reported by openGL profiler. That occurs on every frame! Should it be only once, and after shaders are compiled, disappear?

EDIT: I also double checked that my vertex are properly aligned. So I'm really confused what memory driver needs to allocate on every frame.

EDIT #2: I'm using VBO's and degenerated triangle strips to render sprites and . I'm passing geometry on every frame (GL_STREAM_DRAW).

[image]

EDIT #3:

I think I'm close to issue but still unable to solve it. **Problem disappears if I pass same texture id value to shader (see source code comment). Somehow this issue is relate to fragment shader I think.**

In my sprite batch I have list of sprites and I render them by texture id and FIFO queue.

Here's source code of my sprite batch class:

```
void spriteBatch::renderInRange(shader& prog, int start, int count){


int curTexture = textures[start];
int startFrom = start;

//Looping through all vertexes and rendering them by texture id's
for(int i=start;i<start+count;++i){
    if(textures[i] != curTexture || i == (start + count) -1){


        //Problem occurs after decommenting this line
       // prog.setUniform("texture", curTexture-1);

         prog.setUniform("texture", 0); // if I pass same texture id everything is OK

        int startVertex = startFrom * vertexesPerSprite;
        int cnt = ((i - startFrom) * vertexesPerSprite);

        //If last one has same texture we just adding it
        //to last render call

        if(i == (start + count) - 1 && textures[i] == curTexture)
            cnt = ((i + 1) - startFrom) * vertexesPerSprite;

        render(vbo, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, startVertex+1, cnt-1);

        //if last element has different texture
        //we need to render it separately

        if(i == (start + count) - 1 && textures[i] != curTexture){

         //   prog.setUniform("texture", textures[i]-1);
            render(vbo, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, (i * vertexesPerSprite) + 1, 5);
        }


        curTexture = textures[i];
        startFrom = i;
    }
}
```

}

```
inline GLint getUniformLocation(GLuint shaderID, const string& name) {
    GLint iLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, name.data());
    if(iLocation == -1){ // shader variable not found
        stringstream errorText;
        errorText << "Uniform \"" << name << " was not found!";
        throw logic_error(errorText.str());
    }
    return iLocation;
}

void shader::setUniform(const string& name, const matrix& value) {
    GLint location = getUniformLocation(this->programID, name.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &(value[0]));
}

void shader::setUniform(const string& name, int value) {
    GLint iLocation = getUniformLocation(this->programID, name.data());
            //GLenum error =  glGetError();
    glUniform1i(iLocation, value);
            //    error =  glGetError();
}
```

EDIT#4: I tried to profile app on IOS 6 and Iphone5 and allocations are much bigger. But methods are different in this case. I'm attaching new screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you by any chance..compiling your shaders outside of initialization? Not to state the obvious, but the shaders only need to be compiled once ever. VBOs or VAOs? I wouldn't really expect too much memory allocation going on with either, but I'd suspect it's more likely with a vao where you're pushing vertices to the graphics pipeline every frame.

Comment: I edited my question with additional information. I'm loading shaders on first step of the initialization (before any gl calls).

Comment: can you post the code of commented "setUniform" function.

Comment: I added source to description

Comment: What kind of sprites are you rendering that require you to use multiple textures in this way?  Can you provide some example screenshots?  Typically animated sprites are rendered using a texture atlas, with all of the frames placed inside a single texture.  Is it possible for you to use a texture atlas here instead of multiple textures?

Comment: Is it for simulator, device or both? Had the same behavior for simulator with OpenGL ES 1.1, but was ok on device.

Comment: @Falken I have many texture atlases and most of my sprites are translucent

Comment: @Orange It's on device (OS 5.1 iPhone 4s and iPad2)

Comment: Worth noting that http://gamedev.stackexchange.com may be better equipped for this.

Comment: On average, how many textures are you binding into your shader in a single call to renderInRange()?  Does the amount of memory that is being allocated by the driver in glDrawArrays() seem to be consistent with the total sizes of the textures that are being bound in a render call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved **by creating separate shader for each texture**. 
It looks like bug in driver implementation that does happen on all IOS devices (I tested on IOS 5/6). However on higher iPhone models it's not that noticeable.

On iPhone4 performance hit was very significant from 60 FPS to 38!

Comment: Have you reported bug to Apple? Nobody had noticed this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

More code would help, but have you checked to see if the amount of memory involved is comparable to the amount of geometry you're updating?  (although that would seem like a lot of geometry!)  It looks like GL is holding your update until glDrawArrays, releasing it when it can be pulled into internal GL state.

If you can run the code in a MacOS app, the OpenGL Profiler tool may be able to further isolate the condition. (look in XCode documentation for more info, if you're not familiar with this tool).  I'd also suggest looking at texture use, given the amount of memory involved.

The easiest thing to do might be to conditionally break on malloc() for a large allocation, note the address, and examine what's been loaded there.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I created sample app that sends data on every frame and I don't see any allocations.  I will provide more info later today

Answer (score 0):

try to query the texture uniform just once (in initialization) and cache it. calling "glGetUniformLocation" too much in one frame will hammer the performance (depending on the sprite count).